# Microsoft Sharepoint 2010 workspace search

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would like to know whether the `search` facility of Microsoft SharePoint Workspace allows to search within the meta data columns of documents!

For example, I want to search for a document based on its `DocumentID`.

Regards,

Nami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SharePoint Workspace, Workspace 2007: NO
2. SharePoint Workspace, Workspace 2010: YES
3. SharePoint Workspace, Shared Folder: YES
4. SharePoint Workspace: Workspace from SharePoint server 2010: YES

yoe may look here: http://hansbrender.wordpress.com/2009/07/14/microsoft-sharepoint-workspace-2010-%e2%80%93-coole-features-suchen/

or in my blog, which is written in german: you may translate

Hans Brender